# The meaning and usage of the expression "с моей легкой руки"

Tags: выражения

> Обычно я обедала в столовой колледжа – Пьюк-холле. На самом деле она называлась Дюк-холл, в честь покойного директора. Но **с моей легкой руки** она получила новое неофициальное прозвище.

What does this expression mean, and how is it used?

Incidentally, can other personal pronouns than "моей" be used just as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a more general idiom **легкая рука**, meaning the ability to solve problems and gain success with ease and luck.

I suppose the expression **с легкой руки** may be tracked to this idiom: **started with one's fortunate proposal**.

You may use it with any possessive pronoun or personal name, except for plural ones, because it's unnatural for several persons to share a single hand (and *с легких рук* is not idiomatic). Although, phrases like *с их легкой руки* do creep into language.